# Hardware-based password manager with per-password verification

Tags: encryption, password-management, multi-factor, fips, u2f

I'm looking for a device to perform hardware password management very similarly to the Trezor, [shown here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Jva-vcFQjE), commonly used as a wallet for cryptocurrencies.

Unfortunately, the Trezor only stores a decryption key on the device and instead has to store the passwords online (dropbox/gcloud) which is a non-starter for me.

So basically, I'm looking for a hardware device like a Trezor that can store encrypted passwords within it. When you go to request a password, it will only deliver that specific password to you, not the entire list. The management of passwords and request would be very similar to the video above.

The whole point of this workflow is if- worst case scenario- I accidentally install a trojan or a keylogger then the most that the attacker can ever get is whatever passwords I happen to copy while they are watching. They cannot ex-filtrate the entire password DB from the device because they would need to physically click and confirm every retrieval operation.

Does such a device currently exist?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions of the pattern, "is there a product/tool that does X?" are off-topic as the answer may change from day to day and could result in a long list of products.

Comment: Well, I dont believe a single product exists to decrypt on a per-password basis. It would hardly be a long list.

Comment: The pattern and the principle remains the same

Comment: What is wrong with storing the encrypted passwords on the server?

Comment: One way to do it is by using pass (https://www.passwordstore.org/) and putting your PGP encryption key onto a hardware token like Nitrokey. If you configure the gnupg agent to always require the PIN, you'll have the functionality you seek without needing to store the password DB itself on the token.

Comment: We have a site for [HardwareRecs.SE] . Since you seem to have a pretty clear idea of how the device should work, you might see if this question is already answered there. If not, you could ask it yourself... but be sure to follow their [question quality guidelines](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/205/9572) !! Either way, good luck!